# AWS Lambda NodeJS10.x - error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1

Tags: aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf, aws-lambda-layers

I'm getting an error using **wkhtmltopdf** from my lambda function NodeJS10.x

> Documets Error: /var/task/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

I've added some Lambda Layers **imagemagick and graphicsmagick** but I got the same error

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I did for some reason someone delete my own answer. 
You can check here the solution [AWS Lambda NodeJS 10 using wkhtmltopdf](https://medium.com/wkhtmltopdf-aws-lambda-nodejs10/aws-lambda-nodejs-10-using-wkhtmltopdf-27be1d4a6c79)

Comment: Thank you. I found that article while searching for a solution. But I still have issue with the fonts now.

Comment: Glad it worked. you can use the font directly in your html


`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

css:
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;